# ie shows border when image is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery to change between clases when an image is clicked.
In chrome & FF everything is fine but in ie9 (probably also earlier) when i click one
of the image some ugly gray border appears.

This is the html code:

```
<a id="PASTWINS" href="improve.php" class="PastWin_Unmarked"></a>
```

This is the style:

```
.PastWin_Unmarked{border:0px;display: block;background-image:url('images/tomgui3_08.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;width:206px;height:43px;text-decoration:none;}
```

And here is an image with the ugly border that appears:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can remove it with...

```
a:focus {
   outline: none;
}
```

However, keep in mind some people need this as a visual cue when navigating via the keyboard.